# Perl : get path of the file in a directory

Tags: perl, perl-module

I open a directory `a/b/c/`

`c` has `d1 , d2, d3 d4`

I wanna print the path of `d1 d2 d3 d4`

like

```
a/b/c/d1
a/b/c/d2
a/b/c/d3 and soo on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try Cwd

```
perl -e 'use Cwd 'abs_path'; print abs_path("myfile");'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
use Cwd 'abs_path';

print "$_\n" for map abs_path($_), glob("a/b/c/*");
```

Comment: this seems to work fr my problm. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to canonize the path for prettyness (in which case you want `File::Spec->canonpath` and not `Cwd::abs_path`), you can simply use

```
"$dir/$fn"
```